# Aligning columns with matching values (screenshot)

Tags: excel

I am trying to align columns that contains "french toast". Please refer to the Screenshot. Is there any way of going about this on Excel? Feeling lost. Thank you!

- Screenshot Updated!

[Screenshot-Before-After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnJta.png)

Comment: (Assuming the columns in the screenshot are A, B, and C) - What happened to your column A in the "after" screenshot?  In the original there is "What is frenchtoast", but the after screenshot shows just "is frenchtoast" - how do we know when to remove info. from column A or not?

Comment: @BruceWayne Sorry for the confusion. Nothing is removed. It was cropped from the after screenshot by my mistake. The task is simply adjusting the cells to align column by text "french toast"

Comment: If nothing is removed, where did "what" go in the "After" screenshot?  I see in the second row, you moved everything over. That I understand, but what if "french toast" is to be moved to the left? What happens to any "overflow" in column A?

Comment: I think you have over-censored this data; it is likely that we would see what you wanted to do if the text more closely resembled what your actual data looked like. You can keep it anonymous of course, but for example, is "french toast" a product ID? and each of the other columns is, for example, a product Name, customer name, etc? Because in your example it's hard to see why some sections have words *after* French Toast, and some have words *before* French Toast.

Comment: @Grade 'Eh' Bacon Guys Nothing is removed. If there is an overflow, I guess I would just have to start off from a place where there are enough columns on both sides. This is not for products or services, this is my way to figure out how to organize semantics - I started with a list of phrases where they all contain the word "french toast". I wish for all rows to be adjusted so that "french toast" sits in the same column.

Comment: @BruceWayne + Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: This is somewhat of a large project; this site is intended for specific Q&A, not wholesale "please give me code" requests. Please attempt this yourself and ask questions which identify areas you are struggling with.

Comment: Thanks for the updated screenshot, I see what you are trying to do.  Will "french toast" *always* be in the 4th column? Also, what's the overall goal of putting it in the fourth column, what do you plan on doing with that? I just want to make sure we don't run in to an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon What's wrong with asking a question. I attempted and did the research, couldn't find a solution, I've seen difficult excel questions addressed here, couldn't find duplicate questions, so I came  to post. I am only trying to learn... And for the record, this is my first ask. Relax, dude.

Comment: @BruceWayne Thank you! Yes, I am limiting my data input so that the row does not contain more than 3 words before/after "french toast" (4th column).

Comment: "What's wrong with asking a question." Well the question you asked is: "Is this possible." The answer to that question is "Yes". This site is not intended for wholescale coding projects to be created for you.

Comment: @Grade 'Eh' Bacon I don't see how this question is wholescale. This is only a fraction of the document. My question is it does not seem possible within my capabilities or learning, is this possible to you, if it is, can you point me in the right direction. I don't think this is really the end of the world kind of question.

Comment: You'll need to use VBA for this (unless you want to use some convoluted formulas everywhere on a helper sheet). A good place to start is use the macro recorder to record you moving the data around and setting it up like you want.  Then, you can look at the code and try to see what it's doing, and how to set up a macro.  Then, if you still need help, post the code here and we can help point you in the right direction.  Googling around for something such as "VBA+move data", or "VBA move cell value", etc. should help too.

Comment: @BruceWayne Thank you for your confirmation. I guess VBA is unavoidable :( I will look into your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Just as a quickly whipped together VBA subroutine, you could use:

```
Sub frenchToast()
    Dim rngData As Range, rngRow As Range, rngFound As Range
    Dim frenchCol As Integer, startCol As Integer, writeCol As Integer, totalCols As Integer

    'This is the range containing your french toast phrases
    Set rngData = Sheet1.Range("A1:D5")

    'get the total number of columns from this range. We will use to determine how
    '   far out we need to make the "French toast" column on sheet2
    totalCol = rngData.Columns.Count

    'Loop through each row in the range
    For Each rngRow In rngData.Rows

        'Where's my french toast?
        Set rngFound = rngRow.Find("French Toast")

        'only continue if you found some french toast
        If Not (rngFound Is Nothing) Then

            'Determine which column the french toast is in
            frenchCol = rngFound.Column - rngRow.Cells(1).Column + 1

            'determine which column we need to start writing the sentence
            '   for this row
            startCol = (totalCol + 1) - frenchCol

            'Loop through the columns in this sentence and write them out
            '   to sheet2
            For writeCol = startCol To totalCol + 5
                Sheet2.Cells(rngRow.Row, writeCol).Value = rngRow.Cells(1, writeCol - startCol + 1).Value
            Next
        End If

    Next rngRow
End Sub
```

I usually wouldn't go to the trouble of writing this completely because it's not really in the spirit of StackOverflow, but I love French Toast and the question of how to make a value line up in a new record is interesting, especially when you take into consideration that you have to write it to a new range that can accommodate shifting start and positions for the record.

Anyway, you'll have to change that `Set rngData = Sheet1.Range("A1:D5")` line to fit your data, and you may want to change the bit near the bottom where it writes to `sheet2` but other than that it should determine the best column to start writing each row out to the new sheet so that it doesn't run out of columns.

I've commented the snot out of the code too so it should be somewhat self explanatory. It gets a little tricky with the column determination math, but if you follow it through you'll see what it's doing.

Comment: Haha, looks like Stepani made a wise choice looking for french toast!

Comment: Haha Thank you everyone! This is incredibly helpful for a beginner like myself... I am going to study the shit out of this formula. :) Yay French Toast.

Comment: Totally with the French Toast! I think all SO questions should incorporate French Toast